# Rails: return model (not bound to active record) as xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have a model class that is **not** bound to Active record.

```
  class ProcessingStatus
    attr_accessor :status, :timestamp
  end
```

The model acts as a processing status holder and will eventually be returned to the calling method.

Since this is invoked as an active resource method, this needs to go back (serialized) as xml.
Here is my action method:

```
def activate
  @process_status = ProcessingStatus.new
  if Account.activate(params[:account])           
    @process_status.status = "success"
  else
    @process_status.status = "fail"
  end 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @process_status }
  end
end
```

This doesn't seem to return a valid xml though.

If I try and output the `@process_status` like below

```
return render :text => "The object is #{@process_status}"
```

this is what I get:

> The object is #<ProcessingStatus:0x00000005e98860>

Please tell me what I am missing.

**Edit #1,**

Based on the comment below, I modified my code to include the serialization libraries.

```
class ProcessingStatus 
  include ActiveModel::Serialization
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

  attr_accessor :status

  def attributes

    @attributes ||= {'status' => 'nil'}
  end
end
```

I am getting closer:) Now get the output as follows for .xml request. 
but the value that I assigned is not reflected.

```
@process_status.status = "success" / "fail"

<processing-status><status>nil</status></processing-status>
```

but when i make a json request, it is appearing correct!

```
{"processing_status":{"status":"success"}}
```

Comment: `return render :text =>` This doesn't seem to help much. Can you show the output for `format.xml` such as from your logs or just viewing source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define method `to_xml` in your model, or include Serialization module as below:

```
class ProcessingStatus
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  attr_accessor :status, :timestamp
end
```

Here you've got more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Comment: Thanks tjeden. I am getting closer :). I still have a problem getting the correct value in the xml though. can you please look at the Edit #1 above? Thanks again.